# foreach is not working in php with pdo

Tags: php, loops, pdo, foreach

I am using PDO with my PHP project and I don't know why this is not working. It is not showing any error.

I have a function to read data from a database:

```
function Read_post($con,$table,$limit=6){

    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT {$limit}";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "ERROR". $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

and I use a foreach loop to display the data. But it is not showing anything:

```
<?php $posts = Read_post($con,"posts"); ?>

<?php foreach ($posts as $key) {
    echo "something ";
    echo $key["title"];
} ?>
```

It is not showing the other text as well like if i echo something else only text.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? I assume that `$posts` is simply empty... hence why the foreach never executes

Comment: exactly my thought too

Comment: echo query and run it directly in phpmyadmin

Comment: `echo ["title"];` has nothing to do with your array values. `echo $key["title"];` might

Comment: To see errors you actually need to: 1) Enable exceptions in PDO 2) Print the return value of `Read_post`.

Comment: If it is not echoing anything from the loop this means `$posts` does not have any value. Try printing the values of `$posts` before the loop

Comment: I did all of that it is not showing the array as well if I foreach any  array again it is now showing the carrect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function Read_post, you have this line:

```
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It will not return an array, it will return a PDO object. You can't iterate over a PDO object in the same way as an array. Try this:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result;
```

Comment: it is showing this error now( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\Bootstrap\admin\manage_post.php on line 50

Comment: So, just before the foreach ($posts as $key) line, try this:    
echo 'posts = '.print_r($posts).'<br/>'; 
to see if your query is actually returning any data at all, or if you have a null set.

Answer (score 0):

echo the `$value` of the array in `foreach` or `var_dump($post)` to check the array contains

something

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $value) {
        echo "something ";
        echo $value;
    } ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump( $value )` might be more appropriate, since it's likely an array or object itself.

Comment: it is not displaying anything